# Consulta mysql se demora mucho en devolver resultado PHP

Tags: php, mysql

lo que sucede es que tengo una consulta  mysql en php que se encarga de buscar con diferentes parámetros, pero cuando hago la consulta se demora 13 segundos lo que es una infinidad, me gustaría saber si hay algún otro método mas efectivo aquí les dejo la consulta.

```
$sql1= "select *  from articulos2 WHERE  articulo LIKE  '$dato%' or marca LIKE  '$dato%' or categoria LIKE  '$dato%' or subcategoria LIKE  '$dato%' ORDER BY articulo ASC ";
```

Comment: la cantidad de comparaciones Like es lo que esta retrasando tu consulta probaste cambiar a otro metodo o realizar la consulta mediante un procedimiento?

Comment: modifique la consulta y solo le puse el like al principio y mejoro considerablemente

Comment: Creo que la raíz del problema es un mal diseño en la BD. ¿Por qué pusiste en la misma tabla el nombre del artículo, la marca y la categoría? Lo suyo sería tener una tabla `marca` y otra `categoria` y usar los IDs para relacionar los datos. Con eso y teniendo los índices correctos, tu consulta mejoraría considerablemente. Tres `LIKE` no son nada si tienes bien montado el modelo de datos.